# Dragging AnnotationView and update MGLShapeSource

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, polygon, mapbox-ios

We create a polygon (MGLPolygon) and we are trying to change (simultaneously) the position of the polygon base on the draggable gesture in an annotation view.

When doing this the polygon and the annotation starts flickering. Seems that updating the shape when dragging is causing issues.

Our goal is to end up having something similar to the Mapbox JS example:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/

MapBox IOS version: 6.3.0